# Streaming crypto between OutputStream and InputStream

Tags: android, cryptography, streaming

Is it possible to connect a streaming crypto between FileOutputStream and InputStream, without creating an intermediate file?

The CipherInputStream seems a good candidate but I have not found any example, except encrypting files.

The goal is to save the time of first downloading the complete file and then decrypt it, when it could be done per chunk of data delivered instead.

Comment: You're decrypting, so you need a CipherInputStream with a Cipher in DECRYPT mode, and a normal FileOutputStream, maybe with a BufferedOutputStream around it. You don't need anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `CipherOutputStream`? You can chain any number of output streams, like

```
OutputStream out = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("daFile"), someCipher)
```

.

Comment: I like the idea and its obviousness!  Now I'm going to do streamable components that can be chained together. Next step, finding best practice how a chain able class should be written....

Answer (score 1):

You question is tagged with android, so I assume you want this for android. I would recommend using a higher level api like Conceal https://github.com/facebook/conceal instead of directly using the JCE API.

There are many reasons for this:
1. Only encrypting does not give you security, you also need integrity
2. The default Cipher streams in android are slow for large amounts of data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! http://facebook.github.io/conceal/ solves these type of problems.